# Was an unidentified spaceship recorded by the International Space Station, August 4, 2014?

Tags: ufo, nasa

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9DvnP8Yn88), kinda went viral, the description says

> Date of sighting: August 4, 2014 Location of sighting: International
>   Space Station (ISS)
>
> Hey everyone, I was watching the live cam and caught this glowing disk
>   in the distance. I took a screenshot of the UFO and enlarged it. It
>   has a long line down its middle and a dome on its top, but is
>   rectangle on its lower bottom. You can see the photos of this at my
>   site, www.ufosightingsdaily.com NASA did go to blue screen as soon as
>   they noticed the UFO. When they brought the cam back online again, the
>   UFO was gone.

Is this indeed (as implied) a spaceship?

Comment: The same person [saw a rodent on Mars](http://debunkingdenialism.com/tag/scott-c-waring/) - no kidding.

Comment: @Sklivvz wtf i guess that's enough to bust the whole story

Comment: @Fischer not to our standards, unfortunately. He could be right *this time*. It's probably some debris, I think, but I am not an expert. I was looking for some third party statement but couldn't find any -- instead I found the rodent story...

Comment: Pedant alert: "UFO" does not mean "Alien Spaceship". As long as this (apparently) flying object remains unidentified, it *IS* a UFO, by definition. The answer to the question is trivially, yes. If you want to ask if they recorded extra-terrestrial craft, or a space-ship, that should be the question.

Comment: @Oddthinking yes i know that, in fact (but i dont know if it's true) the nazis tried to build the first circular shaped (ufo) spaceship http://www.naziufos.com/ and then in the 80s usa tried to do the same in the Nevada desert i think, after ww2 many german/polish scientists went to usa so they used them, that's what i know but i don't know if it's true or not

Comment: @Oddthinking the claimant is a person who is convinced that it is an alien spaceship, and this is a NASA conspiracy to hide the fact from us, but they abuse "UFO" to mean that -- the OP is reporting the original verbiage.

Comment: @Fischer: Those (dubious) claims are irrelevant to the current question. "UFO" does NOT mean "circular shaped", and it does not mean "spaceship". Is anyone claiming it is a spaceship (let alone a spaceship built with Nazi technology)? If so, let's quote them, and test that claim. The answer to the previous question is self-evidently "yes", so I edited it again.

Comment: @Oddthinking good edit, I was pondering to do the same.

Comment: @georgechalhoub if you think so, then you are free to vote to close...

Comment: See http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Am I missing something here? I see a faint hazy artefact, that's all. I would not even call it an 'object', could be a lens reflection, video artifact, etc.

Comment: @JanDoggen Falls under "People see what they want to see" IMO. Of course, it could always actually be something. On a different side of the same coin you could say you see it as an anomaly because you don't believe in ETs.